# IE virtual machine files are broken

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, modern.ie

I downloaded IE11 and IE10 virtual machines for VirtualBox from MS Edge page.
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/

But the zip files seems to be broken. Unzip command shows:

```
$ zipinfo IE11.zip 
Archive:  IE11.zip   5314224734 bytes   1 file
warning [IE11.zip]:  1019257298 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [IE11.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

How can I download the correct version of the virtual machines?

Comment: Did you wait for the zip to fully download first before trying to open it?

Answer (score 2):

The files are correct. They are zip64 files and you need a software that supports it to unzip them. In the [instructions](https://az792536.vo.msecnd.net/vms/release_notes_license_terms_8_1_15.pdf) right below the download button we recommend [The Unarchiver](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/unarchiver).

Source: I'm the PM of that website

Comment: If that is the correct answer please mark it so others can find it easily.